# Proguard: Java: Unable to open nested entry 'myfile.jar' It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression

Tags: java, proguard

I am new to Proguard for obfuscation of Java jar files. However, I am facing issue getting it worked.

I tried many combinations to get it work

-dontobfuscate
-dontoptimize
-dontwarn
-verbose

Also, I manually opened the jar file and compressed it back using jar command but I still get the same error.

Appreciate any help or pointers to fix the issue.

Comment: The error look similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542110/spring-boot-obfuscator? Please offer more information and Proguard config.

Comment: thanks, but even in that question the person who answered didn't give the solution rather than lecture/preach. I disabled all compression using the fields I showed but still it throws same error. I will add more information

Comment: @chandank       Did you find a solution for this?  Can you post it please

Comment: No I have not been able to find the solution. If you find then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have a clear question and your question title is pretty much the copy paste of the error I'm going to assume the following:

You are using Proguard to obfuscate a fat jar with nested jars inside.

Proguard compress the jar, that is why you are getting that error. **Nested jar files must be stored without compression.** Meaning the jars you have inside your fat jar need to be store without compression. Since Proguard compress the fat jar it compress the nested jars. There is no control over this for proguard, at least not that I know of.

A fix could be to unjar it, after Proguard is done, and then create the jar again without compression. 
To do this you can unjar it and then use:

```
jar c0mf
```

To create the jar again, the key is in the 0.

```
0 (zero)    Indicates that you don't want the JAR file to be compressed.
```

["Creating a JAR File"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

Comment: I am not manually untarring it, it is done by the proguard, please read the question

Comment: @angry_einstain Thanks for writing this response, it helped me a lot just now.