# Spring boot with proguard not able to create executable jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, proguard, executable-jar

In my swing application I have used spring boot. It's working perfectly until I have used proguard with maven plug-in to obfuscation my jar. Now when I try to launch my application "jar" it provides my error.

I have already refer these questions

[Spring Boot obfuscator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542110/spring-boot-obfuscator)

[NullPointerException: ProGuard, Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065609/nullpointerexception-proguard-spring-boot)

**POM.xml**

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.6</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                        <version>4.10</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <proguardVersion>4.10</proguardVersion>
                    <options>
                        <option>-keep public class com.mycompany.app.Main{public static void main(java.lang.String[]);}</option>
                        <option>-keep public class org.springframework.** { *; }</option>
                    </options>
                    <libs>
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
                    </libs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <finalName>Application</finalName>
    </build>
```

**Error in console**

```
[2016-06-23 18:39:00.110] boot - 240 ERROR [main] --- SpringApplication: Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunnerat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:809)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:790)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:777)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
at com.mycompany.app.Main.main(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mycompany.app.Main.run(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplicati
on.java:806)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.Invocat
ionTargetException
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:62)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:809)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:790)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:777)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
at com.mycompany.app.Main.main(Unknown Source)        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mycompany.app.Main.run(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:806)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the the following method is missing, as it is invoked via reflection by spring:

```
com.mycompany.app.Main.run(...)
```

You need to explicitly keep it using a rule like this:

```
-keep class com.mycompany.app.Main {
    *** run(...);
}
```

Maybe there are more keep rules needed after that.

Comment: Expecting opening '{' at '(' in argument number 108

Comment: Just tested the snippet and it is syntactically correct. Can you post the content at line 108 of your configuration?

Comment: got it, it was a mistake from my end. works fine. Thanks a lot mate.